# AWS Elasticbeanstalk WebSockets

Tags: asp.net, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed an Asp.Net Web API project on `Amazon Web Services`' `Elasticbeanstalk` (IIS configured machine). Everything works fine except WebSocket. To test the WebSocket easier I use [Simple WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo) extension on Chrome.

When I make a request to the API, I get the following (error) message (I observe this message over developer console's network tab):

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://my_url' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I have not found enough information to overcome this problem.

I tried enabling all Inbound/Outbound TCP connections from all ports and all IPs under `Security Groups`.

I tried creating an empty Asp.Net Web API project that only has a basic sample of WebSockets (just sending a message to the connected user) and deploying it to a brand new environment and application on AWS.

Nothing has worked so far.

I am using [Microsoft's WebSockets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WebSockets/), .NET Framework 4.5.1.

What are the possible solution ways?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `All TCP` on `Inbound` segment of `Security Groups` and using the IP address of the server instead of AWS created name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Elastic Load Balancer in your elastic beanstalk then ELB does not support web sockets and you have to apply a work around. Change your Load Balancer top classic load balancer that supports Websockets.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/

Comment: I am doing step by step exactly what they do on the article but I still get the same error. I tried removing current load balancer for the EC2 and now I am not even able to reach to my server. How can I match new load balancer (ALB - Application Load Balancer) with existing EC2 instance? I also tried creating a new EC2 with ALB but I wasn't asked a load balancer so that I can choose an ALB. Do you know about that?

Comment: AWS Elastic Load Balancer actually supports web sockets, you just need to change default listener protocol (HTTP) to TCP (as suggested in the accepted answer and the following [blog](http://blog.flux7.com/web-apps-websockets-with-aws-elastic-load-balancing)